# Notice: Undefined index: Enviando variable por post

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, post, html-select

Estoy realizando un select anidado con conexión a mysql y al enviar un dato con el método post me arroja el error de variable indefinida,realice las pruebas y efectivamente no se esta enviando nada.
Utilizo Jquery para realizar el envió de este dato en mi caso es el id de región

PD: omitiré el código de la coleccione ya que se conecta a la base de datos ,pero si es necesario para dar solución al foro lo publicare.

---

```
metodos.php
function get_region(){
$con = conbd();
$query_reg = "SELECT * FROM tbl_region ORDER BY nombre_region ASC";
if($stmt_reg = mysqli_query($con,$query_reg)){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt_reg)){

     ?> <option value="<?php echo $row['id_region'] ?>" > <?php echo $row['nombre_region'] ?> </option> <?php 

  }
}
mysqli_free_result($stmt_reg);
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

---

```
get-provincia.php

<?php include("conbd.php"); 
$id_region = $_POST['id_region'];
$con = conbd();
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_provincia WHERE idRegion='$id_region' ORDER BY nombre_provincia ASC";
$stmt = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$html = "<option value='0'>Seleccione</option>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
$html =  "<option     value='".$row['id_provincia']."'>".$row['nombre_provincia']
."</option>";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

---

```
index.php

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Trabajos | Check list system</title>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--external css-->
<link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/js/bootstrap-    datepicker/css/datepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/js/bootstrap-    daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media     queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js">    </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js">    </script>
<![endif]-->
<?php include ("menu-encabezado.php");
    include ("lib/metodos.php");?>

<script language="javascript">
 //combo anidado

  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#region").change(function(){


        $("#region option:selected").each(function() {
            //guardamos el id de region 
             var id_region = $(this).val();
            $.post("lib/get-provincia.php", {id_region:id_region
            }, function(dato){
                $("#provincia").html(dato);
            });
        });

    });
});

</script>     
</head>

<body>
<form id="crear-estacion" class="form-horizontal style-form" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" for="nom_est">Nombre</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input id="nom_est" name="nom_est" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="dire_est" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Direción</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input id="dire_est" name="dire_est" type="text" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" for="region">Región</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <select class="form-control" id="region">
                                <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                                <?php get_region();?>
                              </select>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" for="provincia">Provincia</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <select class="form-control" id="provincia">
</select>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" for="comuna">Comuna</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select class="form-control" id="comuna" >
<option value="0">Seleccione</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>                           
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-    theme">Crear</button>

</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no veo necesario recorrer todo el conjunto de "option" para atrapar el valor que se selecciona, simplemente podrías utilizar en el select id_region algo como esto:

```js
function envia_region()
{
  var id_region=$('#region option:selected').val(); 
  $.post("lib/get-provincia.php", 
  {id_region:id_region},
  function(dato){
   $("#provincia").html(dato);
  });
 
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="region" onchange='envia_region()'>
    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
      <?php get_region();?>
    </select>
```

Saludos , espero te sirva amigo !

Comment: Modifique el código teniendo en cuenta tu consejo pero la variable que captura la información por post sigue vacía

Comment: falto agregar el option:selected para que se refleje la option seleccionada

Comment: En que parte podrías orientarme porfavor...